# Is Request Blob Read supported by CoreBluetooth framework?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The core specification for Bluetooth 4.0 defines GATT procedure Read Long Characteristic Values, which is used to request a characteristic value longer than the limit of ATT_MTU - 1 bytes.

Is this feature supported by CoreBluetooth( and iOS)? The peripheral device is a TI CC2541 dev kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is supported on iOS6 anyway - if you request a read on a characterstic that is set up to be longer than 20 bytes then iOS will return that longer data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide more references or samples?

Comment: Sure - if you have a characteristic on your peripheral set up to to return a long value then when you call

[peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];

the delegate will be called back with didUpdateValueForCharacteristic and data of the full length of the characteristic - so this is no different to reading a normal lengh characteristic.

Setting up a long charactristic using the TI CC2540/1 - the TI SDK has nothing helpful in the docs on this - but I put a few pointers in this post on the TI forum here: http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/538/t/221165.aspx